# Не идет авторизация в activeadmin. Как понять в чем проблема?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь включиться в один проект и возникла непонятная ситуация, не могу войти в панель activeadmin на своем локальном сервере, при том что неделю назад все было замечательно. У коллеги проблем никаких, пробовал ставить руби, рельсы с гемами на новую чистую систему ( mint, mac os в виртуалке), игрался версиями - безрезультатно.
Ожидаю помощи в алгоритме, как найти в чем проблема.
Используются гемы: activeadmin (1.0.0.pre1), devise, cancan

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on  http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-03-07 13:07:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-03-07 13:07:37] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2016-03-07 13:07:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=574 port=3000


Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:39 +0300
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (53.1ms)  SELECT   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"cp"}
Rendered /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7c18de4cbcf5/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (18.0ms)
Rendered /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7c18de4cbcf5/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (149.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 944ms (Views: 784.9ms | ActiveRecord: 73.6ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/print-dc80313545ee56b4f0861d100d53df16e909c58545c2ae17db7a965cb22d62f0.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:41 +0300


Started GET "/assets/active_admin-58d7bbc13e24a649c19c695f83c6ff4c31560bea2b32245b2e04d4d41cdf092d.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:41 +0300


Started GET "/assets/active_admin-01877a5096ea1fdc96a6ab5849f381bd5e0e7af0b4eb2271c8a865efdb73a112.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:41 +0300


Started POST "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:52 +0300
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dSGy7bQT1CW8U5wnEXF5VEufVkwWsLrh3dYYtuPnI0gdattt3Vg7IFKKFkyd/fhqqdCL0HNHBqYs0p0gM3rQGA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Войти", "subdomain"=>"cp"}
User Load (45.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "admin@example.com"]]
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
SQL (15.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-03-07 02:48:42.110058"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-03-07 13:07:53.024530"], ["sign_in_count", 12], ["updated_at", "2016-03-07 13:07:53.027631"], ["id", 1]]
(0.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://cp.test.ru:3000/admin
Completed 302 Found in 343ms (ActiveRecord: 62.4ms)

Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:53 +0300
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
 Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"cp"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms


Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 13:07:53 +0300
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
 Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"cp"}
Rendered /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7c18de4cbcf5/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (10.3ms)
Rendered /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7c18de4cbcf5/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (81.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 189.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в логах ни одного `POST`...

Comment: @D-side, привел полный лог.

Comment: Судя по `COMMIT` и редиректу, вход всё же удался, просто остальное приложение этого не понимает. Возможно, дело в поддомене... более конкретных догадок пока нет.

Comment: в последних коммитах действительно правились роуты, но я пробовал откатываться на более ранние, когда вход в админку происходил корректно и проблема сохранялась, отсюда делаю вывод что что-то все таки с версиями гемов или других пакетов, но не понимаю как выяснить с чем конкретно проблема

Comment: Я бы взял `pry` и попробовал вскрыть, что происходит в `Admin::DashboardController#index`.

Comment: @D-side, не могу разобраться, а как это сделать?

Comment: Поставить `pry-byebug`, как можно ближе ДО ключевого момента сделать `binding.pry`, затем осторожно проследить, на каком моменте начнёт происходить что-то подозрительное. Вас там явно занесёт в исходники гемов, в том числе самих рельс, но истина ж где-то рядом.